# UWP AppServiceConnection not getting value

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to communicate between my host app and service via `AppServiceConnection`. I'm using the following code in my host app:

```
using (var connection = new AppServiceConnection())
{
    connection.AppServiceName = extension.AppServiceName;
    connection.PackageFamilyName = extension.PackageFamilyName;

    var connectionStatus = await connection.OpenAsync();

    if (connectionStatus == AppServiceConnectionStatus.Success)
    {
        var response = await connection.SendMessageAsync(requestMessage);

        if (response.Status == AppServiceResponseStatus.Success)
            returnValue = response.Message as ValueSet;
    }
}
```

And my service code:

```
private async void OnRequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    var messageDeferral = args.GetDeferral();
    var message = args.Request.Message;
    var returnData = new ValueSet();

    var command = message["Command"] as string;

    switch (command)
    {
        case "ACTION":
            var value = await AsyncAction();
            returnData = new ValueSet { { "Value", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value) } };
            break;                
        default:
            break;
    }

    await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(returnData);
    messageDeferral.Complete();
}
```

This works some of the time, but other times the `ValueSet` (`returnValue`) is randomly empty when the host receives it. It has `Value` in it when returned in the service, but when I get the response in the host, nothing.

I've verified that the service is indeed setting the value, adding it to the `ValueSet` and returning it correctly.

Note that my service is receiving the request, the host is receiving the response and the response status is `Success`; a failed connection isn't the issue.

Sometimes this happens only once before requests start working again, other times it will happen ten times in a row.

The first working response after a failure always takes significantly longer than normal.

Also, I have no issues in the request from host to service. It's always service to host where the problem shows up.

Has anyone else run into this issue and figured it out?

Comment: Is it possible that your connection is getting disposed in the process of receiving a message? I don't like this using (), I would keep connection open until I don't need it for sure. Also, it would be great if you can come up with minimum example and put it on github.

Comment: @AndreyAshikhmin Removing the `using` and manually disposing at the appropriate time doesn't change anything for me. I'll try to come up with something for GitHub here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the process of creating a sample app I realized what the problem was. I was performing an asynchronous action (albeit a very short one) before my line `var messageDeferral = args.GetDeferral();`. It appears that this was allowing the background task to be closed before it had responded to the host. Simply moving that line to the beginning of the `OnRequestReceived` function fixed the problem for me.

So for anyone who runs into a similar issue, **get your deferral before you do *anything* else!** Spare yourself the pain I went through.